# Inconsistent reputation mouse-over text

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, tooltips

There are 4 locations where user badges and reputation are displayed on StackExchange:

1. The top bar
2. The profile
3. On the "Users" page
4. Everywhere else (ie. On questions, answers, edits, etc.)

In each of these locations, we see the user's reputation and badges. For all of them, the wording of mouse over text for badges is consistent, but for reputation, the mouse over text is different.

1. The top bar:

   "your reputation: 1,000" (colon, comma)

   [image: Imgur]
2. The profile:

   no mouse over text.

   [image: Imgur]

   However, this one actually makes *some* sense that it would be different, since the reputation on the profile is a link to the reputation tab.
3. On the "Users" page:

   "total reputation: 1000" (colon, no comma)

   [image: Imgur]
4. Everywhere else:

   "reputation score" if reputation < 10k,

   [image: Imgur]

   else "reputation score 10000" (no colon, no comma)

   [image: Imgur]

Can we make the mouse over text uniform across all these locations?

Personally, I like the wording "1,000 reputation" (number first, include commas, no "score") as it reads very naturally and is the same as the badge mouse overs (except that badge counts don't have commas).

(It's probable I missed a few locations that don't exactly fall under "everywhere else")

Comment: The tooltips are consistent with the *use case of that location*

Comment: The top-bar tooltip explains what the number is for, just like there is a tooltip for the other 3 numbers. The usercards have abbreviated scores after 10k, so the tooltip gives you the full score. The user page reputation is clearly labelled 'reputation' and shows your full score anyway.

Comment: The last case (missing commas outside users page when rep >= 10k) [seems to have been fixed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321014/add-comma-or-round-reputation-shown-in-tooltip). As of this writing, the others have not been changed AFAICT.

Answer (score 3):

I just pushed fix that add commas to all these locations.

With you in the next build.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that these tooltips could use some improvement.  In fact, I've just added a client-side fix that addresses some of these issues into the [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script.  (It's already in the devel branch, and will be part of v1.34 when it's released.)

The fix appends the reputation score to the tooltip if it's missing, and formats the numbers nicely with commas, like this:

[image: Reputation score appended to tooltip]
[image: Commas inserted into reputation score]
[image: Comma insertion also works on the Users page]

The fix also applies to expanded user cards (which, apparently, don't show the rep in the tooltip unless it's over 10k):

[image: Fixes also apply to expanded user cards]

It doesn't (or, at least, shouldn't) apply to any rep scores outside user cards, such as those in the profile.  It also doesn't modify the *text* of the tooltips in any way; it only reformats the rep counts (and inserts them, if necessary).